# hashCode implementation

Tags: java, hashcode

```
class A{

      @Override
      public int hashCode() {
        return 10;
    }
}

public class SampleClass {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Map map = new HashMap();

        map.put(new A(), "A");
        map.put(new A(), "B");

        System.out.println(map.size());

        System.out.println(new A().hashCode());
        System.out.println(new A().hashCode());
    }
}
```

**Output :-**

```
2

10

10
```

Why 2???. If we are implementing hashCode method which is returning same integer. Should not the size be 1???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't overriden `equals(Object)`, so they don't compare as equal.

Just because two objects have the same hash code doesn't mean `HashMap` assumes they're the same -- indeed, if that *was* the case, that would be *really, really bad.*

If you want two `A` objects to be treated as equal by `HashMap`, you must override `equals(Object)` in `A` to define one `A` as equal to another.

Comment: hey, Thanks for quick reply. Actually I just keep on doing nonsense things with the code :)

Comment: Yup, Just added equals() too. Its working as expected. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, I am trying do it but every time it saying that "you can accept an answer in 9 minutes" or 7 min or 4min. But I'll make it :)

Answer (score 3):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

> The general contract of hashCode is:
>
> - Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently
>     return the same integer, provided no information used in equals
>     comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain
>     consistent from one execution of an application to another execution
>     of the same application.
> - If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must
>     produce the same integer result.
> - **It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method
>     on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.**
>     However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct
>     integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of
>     hashtables.

Thus, when it comes to knowing if two objects are equal, equals is the way to go as Louis pointed out. Hashcode only tells where/how to store your objects given a hash-based collection implementation.